# substituting symbolic array

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to substitute a symbolic vector of the length `x`, where all the entries are symbolic.

First I create my vector `y` with the length `x`

```
y = sym('y',[x 1]);
```

so, for `x=3` I get

```
 =[y1; y2; y3]
```

I use the symbols `y1`,`y2`,`y3` to differentiate in subject to them.
After that I want to substitute the variables with a value, (in my case all `y`s become 0). If I write

```
y(:)=0;
```

I get

```
y= [0;0;0]
```

but later in my code it does not work, because in my equation (which I differentiated in subject to `y1,y2,y3`) `y1,y2,y3` do not get substituted. If I write

```
y1=0;

y2=0;

y3=0;
```

it works great,

Now I need to find a way to produce the `y`s for freely chosen number of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `subs` function. E.g.

```
x = 3;
y = sym('y', [x 1]);
eq = sum(y .* y + 3 .* y);
J = jacobian(eq, y);
J = subs(J, y, zeros(x, 1));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i do use the subs function to substitute the jacobian, unfortunately i can not write it with the zeros function in the subs function because later in my code y1 y2 y3 change size in a loop, so the jacobian gets evaluated for many values of y. i really need a way to produce the y´s.

Comment: Then your question really isn't clear enough, because I have no idea what you're talking about.